# Get maximum values of property from array of objects by id

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
const input = [
  {id: 3, value: 2},
  {id: 0, value: 3},
  {id: 2, value: 8},
  {id: 1, value: 5},
  {id: 0, value: 2},
  {id: 1, value: 6}
]
```

And I am trying to build an array of the maximum value by id, with id as index. For our example the desired output is the following:

```
const output = [ 3, 6, 8, 2 ]
```

I am also assuming that I know the number of unique ids ahead of time, and that they start at 0 and rise sequentially. My first whack at this was to `.map()` over the an empty array of the right length and build intermediate arrays with `.filter()` for each id, then use `Math.max()` on the filtered arrays.

```
const myAttempt = Array(4).map((_, index) => {
  const filtered = input.filter(item => item.id === index);
  return Math.max(filtered);
});
```

All I get out of this is:

```
myAttempt = [ 4 empty slots ];
```

I suspect I'm totally off-base with the `Array(4)` bit, and that the answer might involve `.reduce()`, but I never really got the hang of reduce so any help would be very much appreciated.

PS: I'd prefer answers that avoid the use of libraries in the vein of lodash or jQuery.

Comment: The idea is good, you're missing `.map(item => item.value)` though before passing into `Math.max`. Also `Math.max` takes multiple arguments not an array, so use spread syntax.

Comment: Use `Array.from({length: 4}, (_, index) => …)`

Comment: Aha, thanks for the clarifications and the link to the other question. I definitely got too caught up in the new Array / map weirdness to think through the rest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to collect the values highest value of each key. Convert to array using [`Array.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values):

```js
const input = [
  {id: 3, value: 2},
  {id: 0, value: 3},
  {id: 2, value: 8},
  {id: 1, value: 5},
  {id: 0, value: 2},
  {id: 1, value: 6}
]


const result = Object.values(input.reduce((r, { id, value }) => {
  r[id] = +r[id] > value ? r[id] : value;
  
  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

If all ids from 0 on wards appear in the array, you can add the values by their `id` (index) to an array accumulator:

```js
const input = [
  {id: 3, value: 2},
  {id: 0, value: 3},
  {id: 2, value: 8},
  {id: 1, value: 5},
  {id: 0, value: 2},
  {id: 1, value: 6}
]


const result = input.reduce((r, { id, value }) => {
  r[id] = +r[id] > value ? r[id] : value;
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to do it this way! Will accept as soon as time expires

Comment: "*Convert to array using `Array.values()`*" - no, just start off with an `[]` as the accumulator

Comment: That would potentially create an array with holes (for example not all ids are there) while `Object.values()` won't.

Comment: I'm confused again. Where is `Array.values()` in this solution, and how would I use the accumulator like you said?

Comment: I noticed that if I run `input.reduce` without `Object.values` around it, the answer becomes `{ 0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 8, id: 3, value: 2 }`, is this expected?

Comment: Indeed. I'm create an object, and then extract it's values to an array using `Object.values()`. I've added the array accumulator solution.